# How to use JavaScript regex to find the first sub string until a space?

Tags: javascript, regex

`^([\w\-]+)` can find the first word but it stops the sub string at a . or _. I only want it to stop at the first space.

Comment: `^\S+` \S match any non-white space character [^\r\n\t\f ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `\S+` to match one or more non-space characters. So the regeex must be,

```
^\S+
```

Example:

```
> 'foo.+() bar'.match(/^\S+/)[0]
'foo.+()'
```

Comment: So that would be `^([\^\S+\-]+)`.